# PyCharm - File browser dissapeared

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, ide

I just opened my Django project in `PyCharm` and I can't run server. I also don't see most of the project files unless I switch from `Project` to `Project Files` but they are yellow highlighted and it says that I can't modify them.

[image]

What is happening and how to fix it? Yesterday, I had the same problem with Vue project, now the Vue project works and Django doesn't...

**EDIT** deleted `.idea` and restarted `PyCharm` and now there is almost nothing.

[image]

Comment: There can be several reasons for the yellow background in the files names. Usually it's because you opened files in the editor that aren't formally part of the project (meaning they're not in a sources root). Or it can be library files. Or it can be files that are read-only on disk meaning you don't have write permission with the account you used to launch PyCharm. Or it can be some project configuration where you excluded or didn't include those files. It really depends on your specific project and environment setup, and there can be more than one reason.

Comment: If you delete the `.idea` directory you basically delete the project setup. The way to get it back is "open new project" and recreate the project from the beginning (the source files themselves will still be on the disk, only the project configurations are gone.)

Comment: Please check your project structure settings and make sure you have content root in there. Make sure you have file `.idea/<project_name>.iml` existing in your project root. The issue is sometime caused by VCS touching configuration files from `.idea`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Project file window is yellow in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68614561/project-file-window-is-yellow-in-pycharm)